# How do I manually reassign citizens to work on a different hexagon?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ4, I can easily reassign citizens to benefit from a different tile. For example, from a forest tile to a mountain tile to increase production with the cost of decreasing food. I have not been able to find a way to do so in Civ5. Everything so far has been assigned automatically by the game. I've tried clicking everywhere with either my left or right mouse button in the city screen. Is there a secret button I am not aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the top right of the city screen is an "Citizen Management" button:

[image: citizen management]

After you click it, it shows you which tiles has a citizen on them, and allows you to:

1. Change the city's focus, by choosing one of the possible focuses under that menu. This means it's still automatically allocated by the computer, but now it focuses on whatever you choose.
2. Allocate the citizens manually, by clicking on the grey/green citizen circles that now appear in the main town overview screen. Once you've allocated a citizen, it will be considered "locked" to that tile, and the computer will never de-allocate it.

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the wrong parts.